# Creating Aar how to restrict my application only access that aar

Tags: android

I am creating one aar file. Then I am creating sample application, in that app only need to use aar, other app can't able to use my aar. How do I restrict these?

Comment: The aar is linked into your apk.  The only way another app can use it is if you export the Activities so other apps can launch them.

Comment: If I know the activity class name of aar, we can able to use in other application. Is there having any other solution like permission or protection level

Comment: Not if it isn't exported

Comment: Export is worked.. Thanks... But I need to give access to some applications. For that I can't able to call my aar